# 3 element multimap, sort by the first but count the second number

Tags: c++, sorting, multimap

I'm using `std::multimap` in this way

```
std::multimap<float, std::pair<int, int> > edges;
```

I want to sort it by the first float number, but later count how many **int** (the first one of `<int, int>`) are in this multimap.

for example, 
I have element pairs `(0.6001, <2,3>), (0.62, <2,4>), (0.63, <1,3>)` in my `multimap`,
I want to count the number of `<2,*>` (it should be 2 here).

Is there a simpler way (something like `edges.count()`) than to get every element out and count?

Or is there another container that I could turn to?

#

Solution 1
I'll first store the values I need to count in a `std::set` and count as codes given by [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) or [johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772573/johny);

Solution 2
I'll use a `std::multimap` to store the second and third element again and count.

Thank you both [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) and [johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772573/johny)!

Comment: You can try Boost.Bimap.

Comment: I'll figure out how to use bimap. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: it always worries me to see floating point number as key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
std::multimap<float, std::pair<int, int> > edges;
typedef std::multimap<float, std::pair<int, int> >::value_type ElemT;

int value = 2;
int count = 
std::count_if(edges.begin(), edges.end(),
    [value](const ElemT& e) { return e.second.first == value; });
```